# JSF1.2: difference between ui:repeat, a4j:repeat and t:datalist tags

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facelets, tomahawk

Do you know what is the difference between the tags mentioned in the subject?

I thought they should produce pretty much the same result but it turned out that in some cases `ui:repeat` (a facelets tag) is not working as you would expect, although it's also considered a basic iteration component.

`t` is for `tomahawk` and `a4j` is a `richfaces` prefix.

Any comment is welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facelets' `ui:repeat` has indeed bugs in certain situations. As to the difference with the other two, it boils down that it's not an [`UIData`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html) component while the other two are.

Ajax4jsf [`UIRepeat` extends `UIData`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/apidoc/org/ajax4jsf/component/UIRepeat.html).
Tomahawk's [`HtmlDataList` extends `UIData`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/custom/datalist/HtmlDataList.html).
Facelets' [`UIRepeat` does **not** extend `UIData`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/facelets/component/UIRepeat.java.html).

The inheritable codebase provided by `UIData` is pretty mature (although it is not always as efficient as it ought to be). The Facelets' `UIRepeat` still needs to be polished more. The `ui:repeat` can't extend `UIData`, because it's part of Facelets, the view technology, not of JSF, the component based MVC framework. It was also initially developed by a different team.

Since it's unclear what issue exactly you're talking about, it's hard to tell whether it's actually one of its known bugs or just a misinterpretation/abuse. At least, [here](http://java.net/jira/secure/QuickSearch.jspa?searchString=ui%3arepeat) is an overview of all known bugs related to `ui:repeat`.