# Checkbox inside ui:repeat not refreshed by Ajax

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, composite-component, uirepeat

I work with Mojarra 2.1.3.

When the user click on button "refresh don't work", it refresh the content of the ui:repeat.I expect the checkbox to be checked, just as at the initialization.

What I've found: If I remove h:head in the facelet "refresh don't work" works... Any idea ?

The facelet:

```
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form id="myForm" >
<h:panelGroup id="panelToRefreshOutsideRepeat">
  <ui:repeat value="#{sandbox.columns}" var="column">
     <h:panelGroup id="panelToRefreshInsideRepeat">
     <h2>composite onlyCheckbox:</h2>
     <trc:onlyCheckbox value="#{column.value}" />
     <br />
     <h2>composite onlyInputText:</h2>
     <trc:onlyInputText value="#{column.value}" />
     <br />
     <br/>
     <h:commandButton  value="Refresh don't work" >
        <f:ajax render="panelToRefreshInsideRepeat" />
     </h:commandButton>
     <h:commandButton  value="Refresh work" >
        <f:ajax render=":myForm:panelToRefreshOutsideRepeat" />
     </h:commandButton>
     </h:panelGroup>
     <br/> 
  </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The composite for onlyCheckbox and onlyInputText:

```
<composite:interface>
<composite:attribute name="value" 
                     type="boolean"/> 
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
boolean: <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
<!-- for onlyInputText h:inputText instead of h:selectBooleanCheckbox -->
boolean value: #{cc.attrs.value}
</composite:implementation>
```

and the backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Sandbox {
    public List<Column> columns = Arrays.asList(new Column(true));

    public List<Column> getColumns() {
      return columns;
    }        
    public void setColumns(List<Column> columns) {
    this.columns = columns;
    }

    public class Column {
       private boolean value;
       public Column(boolean value) {
          this.value = value;
       }
       public void setValue(boolean value) {
          this.value = value;
       }
       public boolean getValue() {
          return this.value;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce your problem even on latest Mojarra 2.1.4. It works fine if the checkbox is not inside a composite. This is a bug in Mojarra's `<ui:repeat>`. It is [totally broken](http://java.net/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=project%20=%20JAVASERVERFACES%20AND%20%28summary%20~%20ui%3arepeat%20OR%20description%20~%20ui%3arepeat%20OR%20comment%20~%20ui%3arepeat%29) in Mojarra. It works perfectly fine on [MyFaces 2.1.3](http://myfaces.apache.org/download.html).

You have 2 options:

- Replace Mojarra by MyFaces.
- Use an `UIData` component instead of `<ui:repeat>`, e.g. `<h:dataTable>`, `<t:dataList>`, `<p:dataList>`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to replace with myFaces.

Comment: Try a4j:repeat.

[help/on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023164/jsf1-2-difference-between-uirepeat-a4jrepeat-and-tdatalist-tags)

Comment: @nisses: OP is using JSF2.