# Missing parameter values in invoked method with composite components using ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, primefaces, composite-component, mojarra, uirepeat

So after several days of debugging, we were eventually able to reproduce some strange interactions between composite components, `ui:repeat`, `p:remoteCommand` and partial state saving in JSF that we do not understand.

#### Scenario

A composite component iterates over a list of objects using `ui:repeat`. During each iteration, another composite component is included and arguments are passed.

```
<ui:composition (...)>
  <ui:repeat var="myVar" value="#{cc.attrs.controller.someList}">
    <namespace:myRemoteCommand someParam="SomeParam"/>
```

In the included composite component, there is an auto-run `p:remoteCommand` calling a method using parameters defined in the component's interface.

```
<ui:component (...)>
  <p:remoteCommand actionListener="#{someBean.someMethod(cc.attrs.someParam)}"
                   autoRun="true"
                   async="true"
                   global="false">
```

However, when setting a breakpoint in `someMethod(...)`, an empty string is passed. This only happens if **partial state saving** is set to **false**.

#### Solutions

We tried several solutions and the following ones appear to work (however we do not understand why and cannot foresee any further problems that could occur):

- We can set partial state saving to `true`.
- We can change the composite component pattern to `ui:include`.
- We can remove one or both of the composite components and directly include the content instead.

**Question**

Why does JSF behave this way? What is this interaction between composite component, `ui:repeat` and argument passing that changes depending on whether we use `ui:include` / partial state saving or not?

We're using Primefaces 5.3, Glassfish 4.1, Mojarra 2.2.12, Java 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is all fine. It's just that Mojarra's `<ui:repeat>` is broken. You're not the first one facing a state management related problem with `<ui:repeat>`.

- [Checkbox inside ui:repeat not refreshed by Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111723)
- [Dynamically added input field in ui:repeat is not processed during form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280168)
- [Components are with the same id inside ui:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002555)
- [<h:form> within <ui:repeat> not entirely working, only the last <h:form> is processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808878)
- [Composite component with custom backing component breaks strangely when nested inside ui:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457989)
- [ui:repeat in o:tree not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159489)

Root cause of your problem is that `#{cc}` is nowhere available at the moment the `<ui:repeat>` needs to visit the tree. Effectively, the `<ui:repeat value>` is `null`. A quick work around is to explicitly push the `#{cc}` in [`UIRepeat#visitTree()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/facelets/component/UIRepeat.java#UIRepeat.visitTree%28javax.faces.component.visit.VisitContext%2Cjavax.faces.component.visit.VisitCallback%29) method. Given Mojarra 2.2.12, add below lines right before [line 734](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/facelets/component/UIRepeat.java#734) with `pushComponentToEL(facesContext, null)`.

```
UIComponent compositeParent = getCompositeComponentParent(this);
if (compositeParent != null) {
    compositeParent.pushComponentToEL(facesContext, null);
}
```

And add below lines right after [line 767](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/facelets/component/UIRepeat.java#767) with `popComponentFromEL(facesContext)`.

```
if (compositeParent != null) {
    compositeParent.popComponentFromEL(facesContext);
}
```

If you don't build Mojarra from source, copy the entire [source code](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/facelets/component/UIRepeat.java/?v=source) of `UIRepeat` into your project, maintaining its package structure and apply above changes on it. Classes in `/WEB-INF/classes` have higher classloading precedence than those in `/WEB-INF/lib` and server's `/lib`. I have at least created [issue 4162](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-4162) to address this.

An alternative is to replace Mojarra by MyFaces, or to replace the `<ui:repeat>` by an [`UIData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html) based component which got state management right such as `<h:dataTable>` or `<p:dataList>`.

```
<p:dataList type="none" var="myVar" value="#{cc.attrs.controller.someList}">
    <namespace:myRemoteCommand someParam="SomeParam" />
</p:dataList>
```

You might only want to apply some CSS to get rid of widget style (border and such), but that's [trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles).

#### See also:

- [Should PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING be set to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337015/should-partial-state-saving-be-set-to-false)

Comment: Thank you really much for the in-depth response and analysis. We will just go on with enabled Partial State Saving. I'm glad to know that it is indeed a bug in Mojarra and not us doing something wrong. We spent a long time analyzing the issue until we realized that toggling Partial State Saving solves the problem, but we could not find a reason for this behaviour.